# How to extract zip without extra folder?

Tags: zip, storage, extract, unzip

I want to save space, and when I unzip a .zip on my mac, it makes an entirely new folder with its contents, which takes more than double the space. Is there a way to just the zip into a folder?

Answer (score 2):

for a better alternative, use 7zip. (winrar only has a free trial period, 7zip is 100% free.)

https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

when going to extract a file with 7zip, select the zip folder, then click extract in the top panel.

1. go to the 'extract to' text box and delete the name of the zip folder at the end, or '/*' if you are extracting multiple files.
2. uncheck the box below the 'extract to' box
3. set the path mode to either no pathnames (ALL files within zip folder are extracted even ones within folders inside zip), or full pathnames (all files + folders are extracted)
4. check the 'eliminate duplication of root folder' box
5. although this is not required, it is suggested that the overwrite mode should be set to 'ask before overwrite,' just incase.

now select 'OK' and the files will be sent to the folder that contains the zip folder, without the extra folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use winrar for Mac

http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5169-winrar-for-mac.html

It has ' extract here ' feature that only extracts the contents of an archive